# LogonUser fails when disconnected from domain?

Tags: winapi, credential-providers, windows-security

I'm trying to use `LogonUser()` to verify a user before proceeding in some actions. The user enters their creds. When I call the API when connected to the domain (VPN), then `LogonUser()` succeeds. However, when disconnected from the VPN, it fails (1326 Invalid user/password).

Most of the time I run disconnected from the VPN and I can obviously login to my computer because somewhere on the machine, it must cache my creds or at least the hash of my creds to see if they match.

So, is there any API I can call to verify user creds when disconnected from the VPN/domain? I have tried all the available flags to the API, and none work. Most of the flags work when connected to the VPN, but none work when disconnected.

I take that back ... LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS succeeds...but then it succeeds no matter the creds entered it seems.

I have written a little test app that exercises all the options, but as I said, only successfully pass LogonUser when connected to VPN and entering correct domain creds.

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated...

Comment: At first you of course must call LsaLogonUser instead LogonUser, but this not help with your problem ( except give you more precise error code ). If you can not connect to DC/KDC and no cached creds, you will got error

Comment: *is there any API I can call to verify user creds when disconnected from the VPN/domain* - no. user creds stored only on DC. if exist cached creds locally - it can log with it but it will be local logon only

Comment: @RbMm will try and give it a try on Monday. Will get back to you.

Comment: How i say, LsaLogonUser not changed result, not resolved your problem. But very strange and not efficient solution call LogonUser instead it, especially from credential provider, where you already have ready serialization for it. In any case this api give more precise errors, more options and output data

Comment: The issue you are encountering is that you are specifying a username and password which is only recognized on the remote system but you are running the `LogonUser` code locally so it is going to fail with 1326.  You need to authenticate the user on the targeted machine which can be done with the `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` flag. You could refer to the thread:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-technet-forums/b3ce8a9b-c012-41b7-b7bb-46684ed0f279

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT the *NewCredentials* at all senseless here, because it nothing check at all

Comment: @RbMm Thanks. Got it working. API is such a pain in the ... Has 14 parameters and I was getting an invalid parameter error... Finally figured my source was incorrect, and my cred packing routine had one small mistake... Anyways, seems to be working using auth package MSV1_0_PACKAGE_NAME and interactive login. Again, thank for the pointer!

Comment: LsaLogonUser use `AuthenticationPackage = ulAuthenticationPackage`, `AuthenticationInformation = rgbSerialization`, `AuthenticationInformationLength = cbSerialization`. because you call it usually from `GetSerialization` you already have all main parameters. and look like you have cashed credential in system, so you do cashed logon